# How to change All column name as lower case in Mysql table?

Tags: mysql

A MySQL table contains almost 17 fields. for example

```
P_ID
P_NAME
P_ADDRESS
P_SERVICENO
etc..
```

how to change these all field name as lower case in a single query in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
 ALTER TABLE `table_name` 
 CHANGE P_ID p_id varchar(10),
 CHANGE P_NAME p_name varchar(10),
 ...
```

Comment: Check it for what?